# how to find images in a div and access them with next and previous button with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors, slideshow

I have a div `#list_images` that contain many images.

When an image is clicked, I use jquery to set the properties and attributes of the image in the second div (`#view_image`) to that of the clicked image `$(this)`, this works fine.

I have two buttons (`#previous` and `#next`).

Now what I need to do when the next or previous button is clicked is scan all the images in the `#list_image` div and set the properties and attributes of the image inside the `#view_image` div to that of the next or previous image from the position of the current one.

Comment: Look at this  http://www.tn3gallery.com/examples/tn3_eris_horizontal/

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with your code

Comment: @jmartsch Not necessary as SO has a built-in snippet feature which can do the same thing